# xdan/datetimepicker: Cannot change time from click event

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have to use the datetimepicker developed by xdan. Link to this is below:
https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ .

I would like to increment time on click using jquery but unable to do so.

`$('.set_to_next_min').on('click', function () {
  $('#create_rw_date_select').datetimepicker('getValue').getMinutes()
})` .

So far I'm able to get minutes after selecting a date and time from the datetimepicker but not able to change minutes on click of 'set to next minute' button .

[image: (seen in this image)] .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks